# WordPress: Apply filter/hook to a particular sidebar widgets?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a theme that has more than 5 different sidebars and I want to apply a function to a particular one of them for styling purposes. Basically, the function will modify it's params using a counter to show random 's between each of the widgets. I came up with that:

```
function widget_params( $params ) { 
    // ...
}
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'widget_params' );
```

But however, it will run for each and every different sidebar. Is there any way to make it work only on a particular sidebar? Or alternatively, is there any way to get current widget's sidebar id inside of that function?

Hope all of that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, [don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667) the same question across the network: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106476

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a custom hook and placing it in the appropriate sidebar template. [See do_action for more information.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) Use the following line in the sidebar template:

```
<?php do_action('custom_sidebar_action', 9999); //Replace X with the sidebar ID parameter you want to pass to the function. ?>
```

Then, in your functions, modify your code to be something like the following (Just coding from memory, so might take some finessing):

```
function my_widget_function( $sidebar_id ) { 
    // ...
}
add_action('custom_sidebar_action', 'my_widget_function', 10, 1);
```

With this method, I'm guessing you could get away without passing the sidebar ID, so the cleaner function would look like this:

```
<?php do_action('custom_sidebar_action'); ?>
```

Then:

```
function my_widget_function() { 
    // ...
}
add_action('custom_sidebar_action', 'my_widget_function');
```